# Popovercontroller go away when i try to type in UITextfield?

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

I have one popovercontroller, in popover controller there is one textfield.Whenever i try to type in textfield uipopovercontroller goes away upper left side.Problem is that i want popup enable while typing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and, I just realized after Submitting my Answer, you have an Accept Rate of 0%. That's not good, If you can take the time to 'ask' a question and someone takes the time to help you. You should be gracious enough to atleast `ACCEPT` an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is, while editing is being done on your UITextField, in your popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover: method you return NO. Example below..

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

    if([someTextField isFirstResponder])
          return NO;

   return YES; 
}
```

Mark this is the answer if it is your solution.

Comment: textfield is in another viewcontroller,actually i call xib when popup viewcontroller is open and textfield is in that xib

Comment: Same difference either way, get a reference to the `UITextField` thats in the other controller, in place of `someTextField`.

Comment: Hi skram, I was also facing same issue. Your ans solved my issue. Thanx  :)

One more thing i want to ask u ...  Now my popover is visible always as long as focus is textfield.

How to dismiss it when user tap outside of textfield?

Comment: Glad it helped, you might want to implement the `-touchesBegan:` method on your view. This way you know when the user is touching somewhere on the screen, and if your textfield `isFirstResponder` when you touch,  you `-resignFirstResponder` and manually dismiss with `UIPopOverController`'s `-dismissPopoverAnimated` method.